# error Element id not found on Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, ide

I've been recorded a test case using Selenium IDE and I've encountered an error Element id=XXX not found. Tried using clickAndWait and still nothing happens. Scenario is that I'm on Page 1 and clicked on view then Page 2 appears. Need to check on actions on Page 2. When tried refresh it only refresh Page 1 instead of Page 2.

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/index.php/admin/lead/myLeads</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=search_company_name</td>
    <td>J02217 GMBH Test 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.glyphicon.glyphicon-search</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.fa.fa-info-circle</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>css=span.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=btn-add-file</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=btn-add-file</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Close</td>
    <td></td>
```

Comment: Post your recorded script. Review [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 has been added. thank you. i could really use your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add two things to your script.  At the beginning

```
<tr>
    <td>setTimeout</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>Wait 60 seconds for the page</td>
</tr>
```

And after the click that launches page two

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
    <td>60000</td>
    <td>Wait up to one minute</td>
</tr>
```

Welcome to Selenium testing.  You should try to outgrow IDE as quickly as possible.  IDE is training wheels.  Move to WebDriver as soon as can.  There are plenty of tutorials available.